# How to find all basic feasible solutions of a linear system?

Tags: linear-programming

I'm trying to solve this problem but need some help getting started. The problem asks to find all the basic feasible solutions of the following system:

$$ \begin{aligned} -4x_2+x_3 &= 6\\ 2x_1-2x_2-x_4 &= 1\\ x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 &\geq 0 \end{aligned} $$

How might one go about solving this problem? Thanks!

Comment: There are four variables and two constraints, so $\binom 42$ choices of basis. All that remains is to determine which are feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, this area is completely new to me and I'm no closer to understanding 'how' I could actually solve this problem. What steps do I need to take to determine the basic solutions, and then what criteria makes it a basic feasible solution?

Comment: x[1,4] does not have a solution. So the answer is just x[1,3]
Also, can someone tell me this:
In this case the rank of A and augmented matrix [A,b] is 2 which is less than the number of unknowns which is 4. So the system should have infinite basic solutions right?

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraints of a model,
$$-4x_2 + x_3 = 6$$
$$2x_1-2x_2-x_4=1$$
$$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \ge 0$$

Let's put it in standard form:

$$-4x_2 + x_3 +a_1= 6$$
$$2x_1-2x_2-x_4 + a_2=1$$
$$x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, a_1, a_2\ge 0$$

To start, let's put these values into a tableau as such:
[image]

From here, notice that the $x_3$ column is like the columns of the basic, artificial variables, and as such, we can swap $a_1$ and $x_3$ to achieve a new tableau as shown here:
[image]

In addition, we can divide the second row by 2 to make $x_1$ a basic variable. By doing all of this, we should find two more tableaus as depicted below,

[image]
[image]

The last tableau will be the only feasible solution we are able to reach with these constraints, as modifying the $x_2$ and $x_4$ columns to make them basic variables will turn the RHS negative, which will then invalidate the $x_4\ge0$ and $x_2\ge0$ constraints and make the solution infeasible.

Since we can only have a max of two basic variables with the two constraints we have, and the coefficients of $x_2$ and $x_4$ are all negative, there will exist no combination of points that will allow $x_2$ and $x_4$ to become basic variables in the constraints. Thus, there is only one possible solution.

Comment: Only the last of these is a basic feasible solution for the problem. In the others, since the artificial slack variables are nonzero, the point $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ does not satisfy the constraints we're given.

Comment: Ah yes, nice catch, then there would exist only one feasible solution. Thank you!!!