# A non-degenerate basic feasible solution $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6)$ is

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following Linear Programming Problem

Min $z=2x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3$

Sub to  $x_1 + 2x_2 + 2x_3 - x_4 +x_5=3$

$2x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_3 + x_6=6$

$x_i\geq 0$, $i=1,......., 6$

A non-degenerate basic feasible solution $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6)$ is

1) (1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)

2) (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7)

3) (0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 6)

4) (3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: please help.....

Comment: What do you know about the rank of the constraint matrix?  Can you recall the definition of BFS?  HInt: (2) is not even a FS.  (4) has too many zeros.

Comment: It might help to have a look at [this closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744357/how-to-find-all-basic-feasible-solutions-of-a-linear-system?rq=1).

Comment: yes, got it.....