# Finding basic feasible solution graphically

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm supposed to find the basic solutions of the given LPP graphically. I know what a bfs means, I can find that in other way (I mean by method mentioned in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744357/how-to-find-all-basic-feasible-solutions-of-a-linear-system) post), but I don't know how to do it graphically. The system is:-
$$2x + 3y \leq 21$$$$ 3x - y \leq 15$$$$ x + y \geq 5$$$$ y \leq 5$$ $$ x, y \geq 0$$
Any hint/solution would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Since you only have two variables you can plot each inequality in the plane and take the intersection, maybe this is what they mean by graphically?

Comment: @TonyS.F. but that'll be a feasible solution. Not bfs if I'm not wrong...

Comment: It depends on which one you pick, of course. You will get a polygon of sorts in the plane and if you pick a vertex you will have BFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a linear program like this, the set of all feasible solutions is the intersection of half spaces and thus a polyhedron. A BFS corresponds to a vertex of this polyhedron.

Now, since we only have 2 variables we can plot all our half spaces in the plane and take the intersection to get a polygon. Then, the BFS are just the vertices of this polygon.

[Here is a graph of your problem (more or less)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gcjiozfkhc)

From that graph we can see (0,5), (5,0), (3,5), and (6,3) are all BFS.